# Error on dynamic connection string for an SSIS OLEDB Connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, xlsx

I’m having an issue building a dynamic connection string for an SSIS OLEDB Connection. The SSIS Package is designed to loop through xlsx files in a network folder. The package extracts the data from the files and loads it into 3 different SQL 2008R2 database tables.

This is the connection string I am attempting to use as an expression in the SSIS OLEDB Connection:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";"
```

The error I’m getting is:

Error at Package [Connection manager "\test-0\finance\Test Expenses\New Test Files\Test.xlsx 1"]: The connection string components cannot contain unquoted semicolons. If the value must contain a semicolon, enclose the entire value in quotes. This error occurs when values in the connection string contain unquoted semicolons, such as the InitialCatalog property.

I’m hoping another set of eyes sees something simple I am just missing. It looks right to me!

EDIT: Here are some other connection strings I have tried:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml; IMEX=1; HDR=YES\";"
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"Data Source=" + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + "";"Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml";"HDR=YES";"IMEX=1\""
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::File] + "; Extended Properties=\" Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES\ ";"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::File] + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES\";"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES";"
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties="Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;""
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\\"Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES\\";"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + @[User::Folder]+@[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";""
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::File] + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES\";
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;""
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + "; Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";"
```

EDIT: If there is some other bit of information that would help please let me know. I'm willing to try anything. In fact, I'm in the process of rebuilding the entire project. I new to SSIS. I come from a systems background and I've got experience with development and SQL. Please forgive my poor formatting. I'm also just learning this site. Thanks.

Comment: I'm betting dollars to dumplings `test-0` is a server and this is a UNC path. The `\` must be escaped when you are using it in a string so if @[User::Folder] has an expression of "\\server" it's going to be evaluated as "\server"

Comment: That's correct on both! test-0 is a server name and it's the primary SQL server on this domain. The actual name of the server is closer to FEC-SQL-01 and it shows up properly in the error report. I'm connected to that database in many other ways. There should be no problem there. For the second part about \\ vs \, i'm looking into it now. I will report back with my findings.

Comment: A good practice that I have come across is to never build an expression on an object. I'm a firm believer in *using* expressions but you can't put a breakpoint or otherwise inspect an object's expression. Instead, for situations like this, I'd have a third ssis Variable, of type String, named ExcelConnectionString which is the expression `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";"` Then, if I am encountering issues, I can put a breakpoint or a script task to fire info reporting the value.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, here is the string from connectionstrings.com

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

Which I have reformatted as below (ignore the embedded whitepage)

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=
  c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
  Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

When I reformat your string I get

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
    + @[User::Folder]+@[User::File] 
    + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";"
```

Based on your error message

```
"\test-0\finance\Test Expenses\New Test Files\Test.xlsx 1"
```

It looks like the user::folder and usr::file worked as expected

I am not sure exactly how you are building your connection string, but are you sure the way you are embedding quotes marks on the last line is correct, i.e., should you be using '"' or """" to represent an embedded quote?

IIRC, IMEX=1 is generally a good idea on xls files

ADDED

OK, if you are building by, you should have showed the hard-coded string result. Based on all the parameter based stuff you showed, I thought you had to be building this in code somehow. Which means billinkc is likely correct in his comment re: the UNC path.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. To answer your question, I am building my connection string by hand. I'm trying to get xlsx files into an sql table. That is the basic task. If anyone has any other ideas on how to accomplish this I am open to rearranging this whole process. There will be about 30 xlsx files with different file names a month dropped into a folder. That data needs to wind up in a table. They are in three different layouts but they all contain the same type of data.

Comment: Added UNC path comment

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "you should have showed the hard-coded string result" Is this it?: "\test-0\finance\Test Expenses\New Test Files\Test.xlsx 1"

Comment: Just the complete connection string that you hand built.

Comment: There are many examples in my original post. Here is the one I'm working on:     "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::Folder] + @[User::File] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";" Are you suggesting this is not a properly formatted connection string? If so, please advise me on what I'm doing wrong. I came here because I believe these strings I have are not properly formatted. That's what I need the help with.